# bs4 discard all HTML before a specific tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Versions used: BS4, lxml, Python3.9

Say I have some HTML:

```html
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <h1>hi</h1>
    <div id="hello"></div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

If I have some HTML selected: `legal_div = soup.find(id="hello")`, how could I discard or disregard any tag before that `legal_div`. I'd prefer to use lxml, but if it isn't possible, then html.parser is fine as well.

Edit: When I say discard, I mean that if I were to search for any `<h1>` tags, I should only see "Hello", not "hi"

Comment: Are you looking to alter the html? Or just find a specific h1 after that div?

Comment: I'd like to alter the html

Comment: so remove all h1 tags with the exception of the one that follows the specifc div?

Comment: @chitown88 Yes, exactly that

Comment: Ok, but the solution you accepted doesn't alter the html/remove any `<h1>` tags. With that method, you would still see  `<h1>hi</h1>` if you did `soup.find_all('h1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want. If you strictly just need to find that specific `<h1>` tag, then do as Andrej has it and get that element, and `find_next()` h1 tag.

But if you need to alter the html, you can get all the h1 tags and use `.decompose()` any that didnt follow your specified criteria:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <h1>hi</h1>
    <div id="hello"></div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print('\tBefore:\n\n%s' %soup)

all_h1 = soup.find_all('h1')
print('\n',all_h1)


for each in all_h1:
    if each.find_previous().name == 'div' and each.find_previous().attrs['id'] == 'hello':
        continue
    else:
        each.decompose()


print('\n\n\tAfter:\n\n%s' %soup)
all_h1 = soup.find_all('h1')
print('\n',all_h1)
```

**Output:**

Before:

```
<div>
<p>Hello</p>
<h1>hi</h1>
<div id="hello"></div>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

 [<h1>hi</h1>, <h1>Hello</h1>]
```

After:

```
<div>
<p>Hello</p>

<div id="hello"></div>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

 [<h1>Hello</h1>]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `legal_div.find_next('h1')`. For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <h1>hi</h1>
    <div id="hello"></div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

legal_div = soup.find(id="hello")
next_h1 = legal_div.find_next("h1")

print(next_h1)
```

Prints:

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

---

Or using `~` in CSS selector:

```py
all_next_h1 = soup.select("#hello ~ h1")
print(all_next_h1)
```

Prints:

```py
[<h1>Hello</h1>]
```